# Automapper, efcore, ToProject, IsNull

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper, isnull

```
 public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
}

public class FooMapper: Profile
{
    public FooMapper()
    {
            CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
                .ForMember(x=>x.DueDate, opt =>
                    opt.NullSubstitute(DateTime.MaxValue))
                .ReverseMap()
                ;
    }
```

await mapper.ProjectTo(query).ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);

Does not seem to be

```
SELECT ISNULL(DueDate, 2999-12-31) FROM FOO
```

Any ideas to make the mapping do the ISNULL select?

Thanks !:-)

Comment: Usually it is `dateValue ?? DateTime.MaxValue`

Comment: `NullSubstitute` should work. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).